# Trying to understand how mongoose populate or join works

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I just want to see how to join different collections. Suppose I have a patient collection and doctor collection. I want to do this because a doctor could have a lot of patients and I'm not sure if I should put all the patients into an array of objects in the model field called `patients : []` or do what I was now trying to practice with populate method mongoose.

Now I have another question. If I go with the populate(join) method all the doctors patients would be all together. I think it is weird because it sound like personal information will be mixed up with different people. I know that populate associates a patient with a doctor by associating an Id with a `ref`. Is that a good way to do it?

Anyways I tried playing around with populate and I failed miserably. I'll show you the code below. If you can help me make the joining of the 2 collections like the way I described that would be awesome. It would also be great if you addresses some other concerns.

What I tried to do was associate doctor2 with patient 1.

I get an error :

```
throw new MongooseError.MissingSchemaError(name);
 MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Doctor".
Use mongoose.model(name, schema)
```

Codes

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/population");

var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "connection error:"));
db.once("open", function(){
    console.log("connected")
    var doctorSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        name : String,
        address : String,
        username: String,
        password : String,
        patients : [{type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Patient"}]
    })
    var patientSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        _doctor : {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : "Doctor"},
        name: String,
        illness : String
    })
    //compiling our schem into a Model. A class where we construct documents
    var Doctor = mongoose.model("doctor", doctorSchema );
    var Patient = mongoose.model("patient", patientSchema);

    var doctor1 = new Doctor({name : "doc1", address :"add1", username :"user1", password : "pass1"})
    console.log(doctor1.username);

    //creating a patient for doctor2
    var doctor2 = new Doctor({name: "doc2", address : "add2", username : "user2", password : "pass2"});

    doctor2.save(function(err){
        var patient1 = new Patient({
            name : "pat1",
            illness: "high",
            _doctor: doctor2._id
        })

        patient1.save(function(err){
            console.log("saved")
        })      
    })

    Patient.findOne({name : "pat1"})
            .populate("_doctor")
            .exec(function(err, patient){
                console.log("the creator is %s", patient._doctor.name)
            })

    })





app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("listening on port: " , 3000)
})
```

Comment: You have to give the exact name of the model when you referencing a schema. you have defined doctor in model and Doctor in the reference

Comment: @MariyaJames That helped me I don't have an error anymore. thanks. Now I get when I do `db.doctors.find()` -- `{ "_id" : ObjectId("56a0cb74c5ba46780e4d17c6"), "name" : "doc2", "address" : "ad
d2", "username" : "user2", "password" : "pass2", "patients" : [ ], "__v" : 0 }` EDIT:  should  "patients" be an empty array

Comment: you haven't inserted anything to patients filed that's why.

Comment: I insert things into the patient field by using .populate('patients')? I think I want the patients fields to have an array of ObjectIds of the patients that belong to the doctor. I still haven't got that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Issues of your codes

First of all, please make sure the right model name when you reference it.

```
var Doctor = mongoose.model("Doctor", doctorSchema ); // rather than doctor
var Patient = mongoose.model("Patient", patientSchema); // rather than patient
```

Secondly, after the `patient1` is saved successfully, then find it in the db. Because the `save()` is *Async* operation.

```
patient1.save(function(err){
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
    else {
        console.log("saved");
        Patient.findOne({name : "pat1"})
            .populate("_doctor")
            .exec(function(err, patient){
                if (err)
                    console.log(err);
                else {
                    console.log(patient);
                    console.log("the creator is %s", patient._doctor.name);
                }
            });
    }
});
```

### The Data Schema

As we know, either put the `patient` as reference to `doctor`

```
var doctorSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    patients : [{type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Patient"}]
});
```

Or put the `doctor` as reference to `patient`

```
var patientSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _doctor : {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : "Doctor"},
});
```

Both of them could be OK. However, the data schema should meet your requirement for querying more efficiently.

I prefer to put the `doctor` as reference to `patient`, because one doctor could have more patients as you said. The max size of mongodb document is [16 megabytes](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/reference/limits/#BSON-Document-Size). If we put the `patient` as reference to `doctor`, the `doctor` document could be more larger under more patients case.

Anyway, which schema you chosen to meet your requirement is the first concern.